# Create a dict whose value is the set of all possible anagrams for a given word

Tags: python, anagram

So what im trying to do is create a dict whose:

- key is the word in sorted order and
- value is the set of each anagram (generated by an anagram program).

When i run my program i get Ex. word : {('w', 'o', 'r', 'd')} not word : dorw, wrdo, rowd.  Text file just contains a lot of words one on each line.

Code:

```
def main():
    wordList = readMatrix()
    print(lengthWord())

def readMatrix():
    wordList = []
    strFile = open("words.txt", "r")
    lines = strFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        word = sorted(line.rstrip().lower())
        wordList.append(tuple(word))
    return tuple(wordList)

def lengthWord():
    lenWord = 4
    sortDict = {}
    wordList = readMatrix()
    for word in wordList:
        if len(word) == lenWord:
            sortWord = ''.join(sorted(word))
            if sortWord not in sortDict:
                sortDict[sortWord] = set()
            sortDict[sortWord].add(word)
    return sortDict


main()
```

Comment: `s = "word" {s: [{"".join(tup) } for tup in (permutations(s, len(s)))]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating tuples of each word in the file:

```
for line in lines:
    word = sorted(line.rstrip().lower())
    wordList.append(tuple(word))
```

This will sort all your anagrams, creating duplicate sorted character tuples.

If you wanted to track all possible words, you should *not* produce tuples here. Just read the words:

```
for line in lines:
    word = line.rstrip().lower()
    wordList.append(word)
```

and process those words with your `lengthWord()` function; this function does need to take the `wordList` value as an argument:

```
def lengthWord(wordList):
    # ...
```

and you need to pass that in from `main()`:

```
def main():
    wordList = readMatrix()
    print(lengthWord(wordList))
```